# Data not displaying in iReport and in Java application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have *JasperReports* report which is having *day1, day2, day3, ...., day31* columns. I have table att_t_register which is having *CHR_MORNING1, CHR_EVENING1, CHR_MORNING2, CHR_EVENING2, CHR_MORNING3, CHR_EVENING#, ....., CHR_MORNING31, CHR_EVENING31, CHR_MONTH, INT_YEAR, CHR_EMPID* columns is there. In *CHR_MORNING1, CHR_EVENING1, ... CHR_MORNING31, CHR_EVENING31* columns having values like "PRE,ABS,SUN,HOL,LEAVE.." values.

Based on that values I have to calculate hours in every day and I have to generate report. I wrote code in *Java*. I read and calculate hours and stored in *ArrayList*.

I took *$p{day1}, $p{day2}....* as parameters in *iReport* to generate report. My problem is I am not getting parameter $p{day1}, $p{day2}... values in report.

Please help me.

Here is my java code.

```
public List<HashMap<String,String>> getRecords(String month, String year, int days) {
    String query="SELECT b.CHR_EMPID,b.CHR_STAFFNAME,b.DT_DOB,c.CHR_DESIGNAME,";
    for(int i=1;i<=days;i++)
        query+="a.CHR_MORNING"+i+", a.CHR_EVENING"+i+",";
    query+="a.CHR_MONTH,a.INT_YEAR FROM att_t_register a, com_m_staff b,com_m_desig c WHERE a.CHR_MONTH=? AND a.INT_YEAR=? AND b.CHR_EMPID =a.CHR_EMPID"; 
    query+=" AND c.INT_DESIGID = b.INT_DESIGID ORDER BY b.CHR_STAFFNAME";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    try(PreparedStatement pstmt=JdbcUtil.getJdbcConnection().prepareStatement(query);){
    pstmt.setString(1, month);
    pstmt.setString(2, year);

    ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData rdata=rs.getMetaData();
    int count=rdata.getColumnCount();

    while(rs.next()) {
        HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        String []data=new String[2*days];
    for(int i=1,j=0;i<count ;i++){

        if(!(rdata.getColumnName(i).startsWith("CHR_MORNING") || rdata.getColumnName(i).startsWith("CHR_EVENING"))) {
            map.put(rdata.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
        } else {
            data[j++]=rs.getString(i);
        }

    }
    map=countHours(data,map);
    System.out.println(map);
    if(map.size()>0)
    list.add(map);
    }
    System.out.println("\n"+list.size()+" "+count);
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

public HashMap<String,String> countHours(String[] data, HashMap<String,String> map) {
    int d=0;
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i=i+2){
        d=d+1;
        if(("SUN".equals(data[i])) && ("SUN".equals(data[i+1]) ))
            map.put("d"+d, "S");
        else if(("HOL".equals(data[i])) && ("HOL".equals(data[i+1]) ))
            map.put("d"+d, "H");

        else if(("LEA".equals(data[i])) && ("LEA".equals(data[i+1]) ))
            map.put("d"+d, "L");

        else if(("ABS".equals(data[i])) && ("ABS".equals(data[i+1]) ))
            map.put("d"+d, "-");
        else if(("NA".equals(data[i])) && ("NA".equals(data[i+1]) ))
            map.put("d"+d, "-");
        else
            map.put("d"+d, "8");
    }
    return map;
}

JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(sourceFileName);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
Map parameters = new HashMap();
JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, beanCollectionDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, path + "\\" + fName+".pdf");
```

Comment: You did not pass the parameters (`Map parameters = new HashMap();` - in your code)

Comment: I tried with that also by supplying like JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(),beanCollectionDataSource); I got same result.I did not get parameter values in report.

Comment: We will pass parameters in hash map. but In report when we are retrieving values from database for very record we have to pass parameters $P{day1},$P{day2}....,$P{day31} through HashMap. How to pass because I calculated parameter values and stored in hashmap but for every record  we have $P{day1},$P{day2},... values then we cant store in single map if we store the values which is already there in hashmap overriden. How can we pass parameters? please help me